# WP как кастомизировать постоянные ссылки для записей

Tags: wordpress

Могу ли с помощью WP_Rewrite{} составить кастомные постоянные ссылки для записей? Который день бьюсь над вопросом, смотрю доки, ответы на вопросы, видосы, пробую, не могу понять чего-то.

Есть такая вот структура:

Рубрика 1

(запись)

-- Рубрика 2

-- (запись)

Рубрика 3

(запись)

__ Рубрика 4

--(запись)

2 рубрики, одна является дочкой первой. В каждой лежат записи.

Требуется создать для записей 2й рубрики такие ссылки, чтобы они содержали в теле slug первой записи, то есть

/slug_запись_рубрики_1/slug_запись_рубрики_2/
/slug_запись_рубрики_3/slug_запись_рубрики_4/

В целом мне не требуется полное решение. Только пример того, как я могу и могу ли вообще делать так, менять постоянные ссылки для записей в записимости от их вложенности и категорий.

Comment: а как записи между собой связаны (запись_рубрики_1 и запись_рубрики_2 )? Понятно что запись связана с ее рубрикой, рубрики имеют иерархию. Но как вы определяете какая запись из рубрики 1 будет слагом к какой то записи рубрики 2?

Comment: Такой вот чудной сайт в работу попал. Смысл таков что сделали одну структуру, в требовалась другая для сохранения SEO. То что требовалось другая я так понимаю в ТЗ не ставилось изначально человеку. 

В рубрике 1 лежит одна запись. Одна единственная. Она своего рода главная страница одной категории и она же должна давать свой slug в наследство записям вложенной рубрики.

Comment: сделайте кастомный тип постов, иерархический, и перетащите туда посты. Вот и будет вам родительская и дочерняя запись, как у страниц. А рубрики тут уже не причем

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос был решен, если кому то понадобится то более детальные мысли на эту тему можно найти по этой [ссылке](https://translated.turbopages.org/proxy_u/en-ru.ru.963c1a3b-63a9e865-54876e1e-74722d776562/https/gist.github.com/amurrell/00d29a86fc1a773274bf049ef545b29f)

Если коротко, включаем для записей иерархию, не обязательно для этого создавать свою тип постов.

Ну а дальше регистрация ссылок, подмена существующих, автоматическим определением и подставлением записи родителя и тд.